# fgetcsv - use enclosure character inside enclosed content

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have a problem with fgetcsv() and the enclosure character.

I have a CSV line like this:

```
"13551","Digitaldruck "Blüte x3" ","gelb-weiss"
```

I am using fgetcsv() that way:

```
    public function readCSVData($file, $delimiter, $contentDelimiter)
{
    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');

    $dataResult = array();

    while ($data = fgetcsv($fp, WDC_CSV_MAX_LINES, $delimiter, $contentDelimiter))
    {
        foreach ($data as $key=>$element)
        {
            $data[$key] = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $element);
        }

        $dataResult[] = $data;
    }

    fclose($fp);

    return $dataResult;
}
```

what I am expecting to get is:

```
[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13551
        [1] => Digitaldruck "Blüte x3"
        [2] => gelb-weiss
    )
```

but what I am getting drives me a bit crazy

```
    [14] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13551
        [1] => Digitaldruck Blüte x3""
        [2] => gelb-weiss
    )
```

How can I set up my code, that I can use the enclosure character inside the content?

Edit1:

I need to assure, that a quote inside have to escaped with another quote

i.e.:

```
"13551","Digitaldruck ""Blüte x3"" ","gelb-weiss"
```

will lead to the right results.

Comment: Look at the fifth argument that can be passed to fgetcsv() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: If the enclosure character is used within an enclosure, then it should always be escaped, e.g. by \" or ""... that's one of the few rules that CSV files should always follow

Comment: indeed, but i have no influence to the CSV-file generating progress.

Comment: thank you I will talk to the guy how is responsible for the CSV generation process and tell him that he will escape a quote with a quote

Comment: escape a quote with a __double__quote, that's how MS Excel-generated CSV files do it